# Haproxy 2.1.4 too many SSL Handshake failures

Tags: centos, haproxy, java, jetty

Hi we are using haproxy 2.1.4 as SSL terminator between our own client and server machines(High load machines, always busy) and also requests will be a mix of http/1.1 and http/2.0. We are facing lots of SSL handshake failure in front end. I have enabled proxy logs using rsyslog and get following errors,

> ```
> Aug  5 18:55:35 localhost haproxy[40308]: 127.0.0.1:55442 [05/Aug/2020:18:55:35.364] frontend/1: SSL handshake failure
> Aug  5 18:56:20 localhost haproxy[40308]: 204.xx.xx.xx:45474 [05/Aug/2020:18:56:16.761] frontend/1: Connection closed during SSL handshake
> Aug  5 18:56:22 localhost haproxy[40308]: 204.xx.xx.xx:52088 [05/Aug/2020:18:56:19.403] frontend/1: Connection closed during SSL handshake
> Aug  5 18:56:33 localhost haproxy[40308]: 127.0.0.1:42470 [05/Aug/2020:18:56:33.933] frontend/1: SSL handshake failure
> Aug  5 18:56:33 localhost haproxy[40308]: 127.0.0.1:42472 [05/Aug/2020:18:56:33.944] frontend/1: SSL handshake failure
> ```

Few of the requests have source Ip as 127.0.0.1 but we are doing a plain text connection between proxy and backend as a proxy is SSL terminator here, I could not get detailed logs out of haproxy, my configurations are as follows,

> ```
> global
>    log         127.0.0.1 local2
>    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
>    maxconn 200000
>    user test
>    group testsending
>    daemon
>
> tune.ssl.cachesize 200000
> #tune.h2.max-concurrent-streams 10
> ssl-dh-param-file /etc/haproxy/dhparam.pem
>
> #Default SSL material locations
> ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
> crt-base /etc/ssl/private
>
> #Obtained from https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
>
> ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
> ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11
>
> ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> ssl-default-server-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
> ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11
>
> defaults
>     log     global
>     maxconn 20000
>     mode    http
>     option httplog
>     option dontlog-normal
>     option logasap
>     retries 3
>     retry-on all-retryable-errors
>     option log-separate-errors
>     timeout connect     5s
>     timeout client     60s
>     timeout server    450s
>
> frontend    frontend_haproxy
>      option forwardfor
>      capture request header MONITORID len 64
>      capture response header MONITORID len 64
>      log-format "%ci:%cp\ [%t]\ %f\ %b/%s\ %Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt\ %ST\ %B\ %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ Reqid:%hr\ Resid:%hs\ %{+Q}r\ %sslv\ %sslc"
>      bind    *:8088  ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
>      default_backend backend_eumagent
>
>  backend     backend_eumagent
>      timeout server  420000
>      fullconn 2000
>      server tomcat localhost:9099 check
> ```

and output of haproxy -vv as,

> ```
>  HA-Proxy version 2.1.4 2020/04/02 - https://haproxy.org/
>  Status: stable branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q1 2021.
>  Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.1.4.html
>  Build options :
>    TARGET  = linux-glibc
>    CPU     = generic
>    CC      = gcc
>    CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fwrapv -Wno-unused-label -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-old-style-declaration -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-clobbered -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wtype-limits
>    OPTIONS = USE_PCRE=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1
>  
>  Feature list : +EPOLL -KQUEUE -MY_EPOLL -MY_SPLICE +NETFILTER +PCRE -PCRE_JIT -PCRE2 -PCRE2_JIT +POLL -PRIVATE_CACHE +THREAD -PTHREAD_PSHARED -REGPARM -STATIC_PCRE -STATIC_PCRE2 +TPROXY +LINUX_TPROXY +LINUX_SPLICE +LIBCRYPT +CRYPT_H -VSYSCALL +GETADDRINFO +OPENSSL -LUA +FUTEX +ACCEPT4 -MY_ACCEPT4 +ZLIB -SLZ +CPU_AFFINITY +TFO +NS +DL +RT -DEVICEATLAS -51DEGREES -WURFL +SYSTEMD -OBSOLETE_LINKER +PRCTL +THREAD_DUMP -EVPORTS
>  
>  Default settings :
>    bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200
>  
>  Built with multi-threading support (MAX_THREADS=64, default=6).
>  Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
>  Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
>  OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
>  OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
>  OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
>  Built with network namespace support.
>  Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
>  Built with PCRE version : 8.32 2012-11-30
>  Running on PCRE version : 8.32 2012-11-30
>  PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
>  Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
>  Built with zlib version : 1.2.7
>  Running on zlib version : 1.2.7
>  Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
>  
>  Available polling systems :
>        epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
>         poll : pref=200,  test result OK
>       select : pref=150,  test result OK
>  Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
>  
>  Available multiplexer protocols :
>  (protocols marked as <default>      cannot be specified using 'proto' keyword)
>                h2 : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H2
>              fcgi : mode=HTTP       side=BE        mux=FCGI
>         <default>      : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H1
>         <default>      : mode=TCP        side=FE|BE     mux=PASS
>  
>  Available services : none
>  
>  Available filters :
>   [SPOE] spoe
>   [CACHE] cache
>   [FCGI] fcgi-app
>   [TRACE] trace
>   [COMP] compression
> ```

We send requests to haproxy  from apache(http1.1) and jetty(http2)  httpclients using java 8 and our backend is an apache tomcat 9.0.30+ running using java 11. All our machines are centos 7.x versions.

I have also asked help in [haproxy community](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/haproxy-2-1-4-too-many-ssl-handshake-failures/5563?u=zyber)

Kindly help me to debug this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: That multiple 1-minute delay `SSL Handshake Failure` errors from `127.0.0.1` looks like heartbeat or monitoring requests. Do you have `keepalived`, Linux-HA's `heartbeat`, or monitoring daemon (e.g. `nagios`, `munin`, or `zabbix`) running against your haproxy?

Comment: No, only one tomcat instance is running behind haproxy and that is running in plain text mode. so SSL handshake should not happen between proxy and backend. I dont whats causing that SSL handshake failures, any way to get verbose logs?

Comment: This looks like some clients that does not support TLS1.2 or newer,